# Is this RAM stick compatible with my motherboard?

Tags: memory, motherboard, desktop-customization

I want this [RAM stick](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07R51W1FH) (OLOy Memory DDR4 RAM 16GB (2x8GB) 2400 MHz).

I have a B450M motherboard and a Ryzen 5 3600x. Is this RAM stick compatible with my motherboard?

Comment: There is no such thing as "Intel RAM", there is only "motherboard RAM".

Comment: I would not buy that cheap off brand ram, stick with name brands like Corsair.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Intel-only or AMD-only RAM sticks as mentioned by other users.

That kit will be compatible with your motherboard but, **do not buy that**. Unknown brand with only 1 review which is already negative is not a good sign.

With that said, check your motherboard [memory support list](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/B450M-DS3H-rev-10/support#support-doc) (this is an example for the B450M DS3H motherboard because you haven't specified a model) and buy a RAM kit from a reputable brand.

You can also think of faster RAM if you wish but as speeds increase, price increases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this RAM will work on your AMD motherboard.

RAM is almost always compatible between AMD and Intel platforms. The RAM kit linked above is supposed to be 100% compatible with your AMD setup. As long as the memory is of the same type (DDR4, DDR3, etc) and the same size (288-Pin) as the recommended memory for your motherboard, they should be compatible.

On a side note though: I do not recommend this memory module given the poor review. Given it is from amazon though, returns are usually possible in the event of defective modules.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as Intel or AMD only ram, that ram should work fine for you but if you are looking for a 16gb kit in the 50-65 price range then id suggest something such as [this](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/mcH8TW/gskill-aegis-16-gb-2-x-8-gb-ddr4-3200-memory-f4-3200c16d-16gis) Its faster and from a better known brand than the one you have listed.